# Crystal report Formula issue in if statement

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I created a crystal report and I added a Formula Field (stock).
This is the formula I added to this field (Basic Syntax):

```
if not IsNull ({LigneBonLivraison.Quantite}) Then
    {@stock} = {Article.StockActuel} - {LigneBonLivraison.Quantite}
else
    {@stock} = {Article.StockActuel}
```

But I get this error  "A Statement is expected here" in this line:

> {@stock} = {Article.StockActuel} - {LigneBonLivraison.Quantite}

So how to fix it??

Comment: I thought it was `formula=`, not `{@variable}=`

Answer (score 1):

for binding use `:=` instead of `=`

```
  if not IsNull ({LigneBonLivraison.Quantite}) Then
{@stock} := {Article.StockActuel} - {LigneBonLivraison.Quantite}
else
{@stock} := {Article.StockActuel}
```

for more information refer this link [If Expressions (Crystal Syntax)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms225356(v=vs.80).aspx)

for basic syntax use `End If` at end of if:

```
 if not IsNull ({LigneBonLivraison.Quantite}) Then
    {@stock} = {Article.StockActuel} - {LigneBonLivraison.Quantite}
    else
    {@stock} = {Article.StockActuel}
End If
```

the If-Then-Else statements in Basic syntax differ from those Crystal syntax versions described previously. Basic syntax follows the more typical If-Then-Else-EndIf approach familiar to Basic language programmers. In particular, this makes performing multiple actions as the result of a single If-Then-Else statement more straightforward by introducing the End If clause:

```
 If <test> Then 
 <statement> 
 <statement> 
 <more statements> 
 Else 
 <statement> 
 <statement> 
 <more statements> 
 End If
```

Also, you can use the Basic syntax ElseIf clause (don't forget it's one word ”no space) to allow nesting of multiple If conditions in one statement:

```
If <first test> Then 
 <statements> 
 ElseIf <second test> Then 
 <second test statements> 
 Else 
 <statements if first test fails> 
 End If
```

Comment: But i 'm using Basic Syntax